# Semantic-ui remote dropdown doesn't search. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

**My objective**

Search text and result on a dropdown list from remote data in real time
(execute and result data on keyup event dropdown)

**My HTML**

```
        <label class="lbPessoaTipo">Tipo</label>
        <div class="ui selection dropdown search input mini pessoaTipoIdDropdown">
             <input type="hidden" class="input PessoaTipoId" name="PessoaTipoId" tabindex="0">
             <div class="menu"></div>
             <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
             <input class="search input">
             <div class="default text">Pessoa Tipo</div>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax({
    url: base_url("system_data/pessoaTipo"),
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{

    },
    success: function(ret){
        result = ret;
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('.pessoaTipoIdDropdown').dropdown({
            on: 'click',
            //showOnFocus: false,
            fields:{
                name: "text", 
                value: "value" 
            },
                onChange: function(){

                },
                onShow: function(){

                },
                apiSettings:{
                    response:{
                        success: true,
                        results: result
                    }
                }
        }).dropdown("set value",1).dropdown("set text","Pessoa Fisica")

    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Successfully using the get method. "SysDropdown/dpGepFornecedor?data={query}" on {query} is value of keyup event.
I need send value using the post method. Ty...

```
$(".GepPessoaId").dropdown({ 
    forceSelection: false,
    onChange: function(value, text){

    },
    onShow: function(){

    },
    apiSettings: {
        url: base_url("SysDropdown/dpGepFornecedor?data={query}"),
        dataType: "json",
        method: "get"
     }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your returned result set from "system_data/pessoaTipo" is returning the same data set. It looks like you only made one ajax call and stored the data into `result`. Therefore, your dropdown library only knows of one `result`.

You may be better off calling an asynchronous function that queries from your server everytime you type in new text into the search input. I am not sure how semantic dropdown works, but are you sure you are supposed to be using on: 'click'? If you are looking for keypresses, I don't know if click is the correct event to be listening to.

Looking at the semantic-ui API's documentation, it looks like you can use responseAsync in `apiSettings`
http://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/api.html#/settings

Using your snippet of code, you can do something like...

```
$('.pessoaTipoIdDropdown').dropdown({
        on: 'click',   // Not sure about this event...
        //showOnFocus: false,
        fields:{
            name: "text", 
            value: "value" 
        },
            onChange: function(){

            },
            onShow: function(){

            },
            apiSettings:{

                responseAsync: function (settings, callback) {
                    var result;
                    var response = {
                        success: true   // docs say you need to return success: true
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: base_url("system_data/pessoaTipo"),
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data:{

                        },
                        success: function(ret){
                            result = ret;
                        },
                        complete: function(){
                            response.results = result;
                            callback (response);  // Important to call the callback!
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}).dropdown("set value",1).dropdown("set text","Pessoa Fisica")
```

I believe you need to pass in a query that returns back a new result based on your search parameters. If your data set is small, you can probably cache your result somewhere and filter from the client side.